# How can I trigger a sequence of animations using asynchronous events?

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, android-animation

I have an activity which contains a handler, which handles asynchronous messages. When I get a message, I want to trigger an animation; after that, when I get another message, I want to trigger another animation, but only after the last one has finished.

What's the cleanest way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an animation listener to determine when the animation has finished. Something like this:

```
    Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this.getContext(), R.anim.animation);

    a.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            if(receivedMessage == true){
                startNextAnimation();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: How should startNextAnimation() pick the next animation? For example, when I get a new message, I could put an animation in a blocking queue and pick it from there, but then, what if when the method is called the next message hasn't arrived yet? I think it wouldn't work

Comment: You could create a listener. onMessageReceived() and handle logic for what should happen. in onMessageReceived you would set "receivedMessage = true". which would allow the current animation to continue. if the animation has already finished, then you know to start the next animation when the message is received. (you could keep track of the animations and set it to null if no animation is happening)

ie: if (currentAnimation == null) startNewAnimation()